# Trouble with Variable Scope when Writing a Graphing function

Tags: r, ggplot2

There's an issue where I'm trying to write a script, 'kmeans.R', but I'm receiving errors about a variable not being found. The error is only raised in functions where I try to create graphs, not return a dataframe. Here's the function that returns the parameters I need for the subsequent dataframes and graphs:

```
simulations <- function(nrow, ncol){
  # Generate continuous normally distributed variables.
  dataCont <- data.frame(matrix( 
    rnorm(nrow*ncol, mean=0,sd=1), nrow, ncol))

  # Generate categorical normally distributed variables.
  dataCat <- data.frame(matrix(
    rnorm(nrow*ncol, mean=0,sd=1), nrow, ncol))
  dataCat[dataCat <= 0] <- 0
  dataCat[dataCat > 0] <- 1

  # return values
  return(list(dataCont= dataCont, dataCat= dataCat))
}
```

This is an example of a function that accepts parameters from simulations().

```
getKmeans <- function(dataCont, dataCat, dataOut){
    # Continuous variables
    cont <- kmeans(dataCont, centers = 3, iter.max= 100, 
                   algorithm="Hartigan-Wong")

    # Categorical variables
    cat <- kmeans(dataCat, centers = 3, iter.max= 100,
                  algorithm="Hartigan-Wong")

    # Categorical as outliers
    catout <- kmeans(dataOut, centers = 3, iter.max= 100,
                     algorithm="Hartigan-Wong")
    return(list(cont= cont,
                cat= cat,
                catout= catout))
}
```

Here's how I would call getKmeans() from within 'kmeans.R'; it accepts the parameters from simulations() without issue:

```
kmResults <- getKmeans(dataCont= sim$dataCont,
                       dataCat= sim$dataCat,
                       dataOut= dataOut)
```

However, when I use the following function to create some scatterplots:

```
scatterplots <- function(dataCont, dataCat, dataOut){
## Various scatterplots for generated data

  ggplot(dataCont)+
    ggtitle("Continuous normally distributed variables") +
    geom_point(aes(x=dataCont$X1, y=dataCont$X2), size=3)
  ggsave("plots/cont_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 1

  # scatterplot for categorical normally distributed vars.
  ggplot(dataCat)+
    ggtitle("Categorical normally distributed variables") +
    geom_point(aes(x=dataCat$X1, y=dataCat$X2), size=3)
  ggsave("plots/cat_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 2

 # scatterplot for categorical outliers 
 ggplot(dataOut)+
    ggtitle("Categorical variables with outliers") +
    geom_point(aes(x=dataOut$X1, y=dataOut$X2), size=3)
 ggsave("plots/cat_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 3
}
```

Then R raises an error stating that "object 'dataCont' not found". The only explanation that occurs to me is that there's an issue with variable scoping. This doesn't quite make sense because the error is only raised when I call a function that generates some graphs (using ggplot2).

Could you please help me understand the best approach to resolve this issue? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scoping issue has to do with how you are specifying your variables in `aes()`. You don't qualify them with `some_data_frame$some_variable`, just `some_variable` when working with `ggplot2`. This should solve the problem:

```
scatterplots <- function(dataCont, dataCat, dataOut){
## Various scatterplots for generated data

  ggplot(dataCont)+
    ggtitle("Continuous normally distributed variables") +
    geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2), size=3)
  ggsave("plots/cont_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 1

  # scatterplot for categorical normally distributed vars.
  ggplot(dataCat)+
    ggtitle("Categorical normally distributed variables") +
    geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2), size=3)
  ggsave("plots/cat_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 2

 # scatterplot for categorical outliers 
 ggplot(dataOut)+
    ggtitle("Categorical variables with outliers") +
    geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2), size=3)
 ggsave("plots/cat_scatter.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=100) #plot 3
}
```